# Node.js precision coverage with Inspector API

Tags: javascript, node.js, code-coverage, v8, instrumentation

I am using the [Inspector API](https://v8.dev/blog/javascript-code-coverage#for-embedders) to get precision coverage for JavaScript. I have implemented a target function in `target.js` (line annotations in target.js are added to reference them in the explanation) and a test runner in `main.js` that is supposed to collect precise coverage information. You can test the setup for yourself by running `node main.js`.

```
const inspector = require("node:inspector");
const fs = require("fs");

const target = require("./target.js").target;

async function run(session, data) {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        session.post("Profiler.startPreciseCoverage", { callCount: true, detailed: true }, (err) => {
            err ? reject(err) : resolve();
        });
    });

    console.log("Input: ", data, " - Output: ", target(data));

    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        session.post("Profiler.takePreciseCoverage", (err, params) => {
            err ? reject(err) : resolve(params);
        });
    });
}

function printCoverage(result) {
    const content = fs.readFileSync("./target.js", { encoding: "utf-8" });

    for (let scriptCoverage of result) {
        if (!scriptCoverage.url.endsWith("target.js")) {
            continue;
        }

        for (let func of scriptCoverage.functions) {
            for (let range of func.ranges) {
                console.log(
                    func.functionName,
                    range.startOffset,
                    range.endOffset,
                    range.count,
                    content.substring(range.startOffset, range.endOffset).replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll("\t", " ").replaceAll("    ", " ")
                );
            }
        }
    }
}

async function main() {
    inspector.open(9696);

    const session = new inspector.Session();
    session.connect();

    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        session.post("Profiler.enable", (err) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }

            resolve();
        });
    });

    const param1 = await run(session, "a");
    printCoverage(param1.result);

    const param2 = await run(session, "ab");
    printCoverage(param2.result);

    const param3 = await run(session, "ac");
    printCoverage(param3.result);
}

main();
// main.js
```

```
/* 1: */ function target(data) {
/* 2: */     if (data.length === 1) {
/* 3: */         return 1;
/* 4: */     }
/* 5: */ 
/* 6: */     if (data.length == 2) {
/* 7: */         if (data[0] === "a" && data[1] === "b") {
/* 8: */             return 2;
/* 9: */         }
/* a: */ 
/* b: */         if (data[0] === "a") {
/* c: */             return 3;
/* d: */         }
/* e: */     }
/* f: */ }

module.exports = {
    target: target
};
// target.js
```

Unfortunately, the output below looks quite unintuitive to me. I would have expected the coverage information to be:

- 'a': lines 1-3
- 'ab': lines 1-8
- 'ac': lines 1,2,6,7,b,c (Edit 1: Fixed ranges)

Instead, the coverage output simply seems to tell me that the target()-function is covered and certain ranges in target() are not covered. Am I using the API wrong? Or is my expectation for block coverage wrong? How do I get 'true' basic block coverage in JavaScript?

```
Input:  a  - Output:  1
target 0 259 1 function target(data) { if (data.length === 1) {  return 1; } if (data.length == 2) {  if (data[0] === "a" && data[1] === "b") {   return 2;  }  if (data[0] === "a") {   return 3;  } }}
target 76 257 0  if (data.length == 2) {  if (data[0] === "a" && data[1] === "b") {   return 2;  }  if (data[0] === "a") {   return 3;  } }
Input:  ab  - Output:  2
target 0 259 1 function target(data) { if (data.length === 1) {  return 1; } if (data.length == 2) {  if (data[0] === "a" && data[1] === "b") {   return 2;  }  if (data[0] === "a") {   return 3;  } }}
target 51 76 0 {  return 1; }
target 187 251 0   if (data[0] === "a") {   return 3;  }
Input:  ac  - Output:  3
target 0 259 1 function target(data) { if (data.length === 1) {  return 1; } if (data.length == 2) {  if (data[0] === "a" && data[1] === "b") {   return 2;  }  if (data[0] === "a") {   return 3;  } }}
target 51 76 0 {  return 1; }
target 154 187 0 {   return 2;  }
```

Edit 1:

I think the picture below is better suited to explain my expectations. There are 9 basic blocks in the source code (if you include the implicit return undefined) and I want to retrieve which basic blocks have been covered.

For example, the input "ab" would cover the five blocks A,B,E,G,I. However, from the Inspector API, I only get the information that the entire function is covered and that certain bytes from this function are not covered. From this I can (as far as I can tell) neither derive the number of basic blocks in the function nor the blocks executed.

[image: Flow diagram of the source code]

Comment: It seems like it tells you for each block when it was entered, isn't that exactly what you want?

Comment: @Bergi I don't think so. For example, for 'ab' I get the information that the byte range [0,259] has been covered and that [51,76] + [187,251] have not been covered. Even if I start merging the information (i.e. covered regions are [0, 51] + [76, 187] + [251, 259]), I don't know how many blocks are covered, since the range [76, 187] silently includes the basic blocks B-E-G-I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the function in the [v8 source code](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/debug/debug-coverage.cc;l=454-467;drc=283791d250fe8cce64e1d973116faf92ddd304e4) responsible for merging basic blocks. As a quick fix, I removed the calls after `RewritePositionSingletonsToRanges` and it seems to work:

```
input:  ab
function: target

Start   | End   | Count
================================================
49      | 324   | 1     |
100     | 125   | 0     |
125     | 154   | 1     |
154     | 307   | 1     |
184     | 202   | 0     |
204     | 237   | 0     |
237     | 268   | 1     |
268     | 301   | 0     |
307     | 323   | 1     |
```

Note, that a function has to be called at least once since profiling started to appear in the list. For example, if we have the calls:

```
startCoverage();
foo()
takeCoverage();
rareFoo();
takeCoverage();
foo();
takeCoverage();
```

the function `rareFoo` (and its basic blocks) will only appear in the second and third coverage information.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I using the API wrong?

It looks like you're getting the expected results, so no, you're using the API correctly.

> Or is my expectation for block coverage wrong?

Apparently :-)
The output you get matches what the [documentation](https://v8.dev/blog/javascript-code-coverage#for-embedders) you've linked to describes. Why would you expect to get anything different?

> 'ac': lines 1-7,b,c

This specific expectation is quite clearly wrong: `'ac'`, having length 2, definitely wouldn't execute line 3, and whether it executes lines 4 and/or 5 (neither of which contains any statements) is a question of definition. As you can see from the output, the Inspector API considers the closing `}` in line 4 (along with the corresponding opening `{` on line 2) not-executed for this input.

> How do I get 'true' basic block coverage in JavaScript?

I don't know what you mean.
The data is all there; you can map offsets to line numbers if that's what you want. Note that per-line representations can be quite inaccurate: minified JS code often has multiple functions on the same line (in fact, your entire `target.js` example could be written as one line). The per-character information you're getting from the Inspector API is more accurate, and works equally well regardless of how the inspected code is formatted.

Comment: You are right about the 'ac' example, that was a blunder on my part. I have updated the question to better explain what I expected from the Inspector API. As far as I can tell from your answer, my problem is not solvable with the Inspector API, right?

Comment: @JonasMöller Looks like it. I only know what the documentation says: the Inspector API informs you which parts of the JS source have been executed (e.g. by a test suite); it doesn't offer control flow analysis.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just merge the ranges, no. You'll need to build the abstract syntax tree and your block diagram first.

> From this I can not derive the number of basic blocks in the function

That seems true, you'll have to parse the code and split it into blocks yourself.

> nor can I derive the blocks executed

I disagree. The count of the sub-blocks is `0`, meaning they were skipped over. So for the example input `ab` you'd have to do compute `[0 259] - [51 76] - [187 251]`, arriving at blocks `A, B, E, G, I, D`, although with control flow analysis you can derive that `D` was not executed after `I`.

Comment: Thanks, but that seems like an awful lot of work (building AST + control flow analysis) given that v8 must have already done this :/

Comment: Must it? Maybe it does it dynamically during interpretion, not building ranges for code that's never executed. Or maybe it throws them away if the parent block has the same execution count, to save on size of the returned data structure. (I don't know, these are guesses - jmrk or someone from the V8 design team would be better suited to answer this). [The page you linked](https://v8.dev/blog/javascript-code-coverage#for-embedders) states "*we […] report the collection of **interesting** source ranges together with their block counts*" (emph mine).

Comment: Also in [the design document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wCydi2HEZRF0skDeLb6CH0abZnTyVo5Vz5u-jhwi7es/edit) (linked from the page you found) they say "*Counters are block-based (incremented at the beginning of a block)*" - as I had guessed - "*rather than edge-based (incremented at branches) since an edge-based design does not interact well with catch and finally blocks and block-based counts translate well to the intended UI.*" If you're planning a different UI, it's on you :-/ (By "block", they mean nested blocks/ranges (`{…}` in code), you seem to mean "control flow graph node").

Comment: Ah okay, that is unfortunate. In libFuzzer's documentation there's a distinction between basic block coverage and edge coverage and I thought the same distinction was made here.

Comment: In the design doc you linked, they are in fact talking about "basic blocks". So the CoverageInfo class probalbly contains the information I'm looking for, but unfortunately its's only available to the v8 internals.